# Passing Functor with state as parameter in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, callback

I'm trying to implement a simple callback using Functor objects. I have a Caller class with `print(string)` function which invokes the callback passing the input string. In the callback, I'm collecting all the strings, and print it later in `printEverything` method. But even though callbacks are happening (as verified by output), but nothing gets printed in `printEverything` method.

```
class Callback {
public:
  Callback() {
    cout << "constructing Callback..." << std::endl;
  }

  void operator()(std::string data) {
    cout << "Adding record in callback: " << data << std::endl;
    records.push_back(data);
  }

  void printEverything() {
    cout << "Printing everything: " << std::endl;
    for(auto a : records) {
      cout << a;
    }
  }

private:
  std::vector<string> records;
};

class Caller {
public:
  template <typename Func>
  Caller(Func&& func) : cb_ (func){
  }

  void print(std::string str) {
    cb_(str);
    cout << "Printing in caller: " << str << std::endl;
  }

private:
  std::function<void(std::string)> cb_;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Callback callback;
  Caller caller(callback);

  caller.print("Hello");
  caller.print("World");

  callback.printEverything(); // This doesn't print any records
}
```

Output:

```
constructing Callback...
Adding record in callback: Hello
Printing in caller: Hello
Adding record in callback: World
Printing in caller: World
Printing everything:
```

It seems, the callbacks are happening on a different object than what I have in main scope. Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: Look into *value semantics*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat main function is included in first code block.

Comment: @RandomQuestion Apparently I need more sleep. :|

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `std::move(func)` doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: @RandomQuestion `Func&& func` is actually a forwarding reference there (as `Func` is a template parameter of the function), so you should rather use `std::forward<Func>(func)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::function` copies (or moves if you moved into it) the function you pass to it (see its [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function)). Ergo, the callbacks *are* happening on a different object than `callback`.

If you want to pass a reference to the function, use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) – it has an `operator()`:

```
int main() {
  Callback callback;
  // Be careful with lifetime management. `caller` must not outlast `callback`
  Caller caller(std::ref(callback));

  caller.print("Hello");
  caller.print("World");

  callback.printEverything();
}
```

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PBAlU2kWJxDmBMfb)

Comment: Awesome! I was trying to use `&callback` but that didn't work.